html element not being executed
Whenever i am trying to run below line of code, its not executing <br> as break line  but actually executing it as string.
const firstFiveLetters = chartData.centerText.slice(0, 5);
const remainingLetters = chartData.centerText.slice(5);

// Return the text with line break after the first five letters
return `${firstFiveLetters}<br>${remainingLetters}`;

I am expecting a line break after the execution of first but its not executing above html element.

We need more context; how are you using the returned string?

This isn't a very react way of formatting text, just add the linebreak in the JSX return rather than forcing the parsing of an arbritray HTML string.

you're returning a string, instead return a jsx fragment <>{first}{last}</> or you can return html as a a string but will need to render it with the dangerouslySetInnerHTML prop

I think that the problem is that you are not rendering firstFiveLetters as HTML, so it is detected as a string;
const firstFiveLetters = chartData.centerText.slice(0, 5);
const remainingLetters = chartData.centerText.slice(5);
//Render the variable with the desired content as HTML using __html:
const htmlString = `${firstFiveLetters}<br>${remainingLetters}`;
return { __html: htmlString };


I think you're on the right track, but if centerText contains any HTML, this will render it rather than escaping it—and that could lead to an XSS escape. We don't know all of the OP's constraints but perhaps something like <>{firstFiveLetters}<br>{remainingLetters}</> in JSX (or equivalent in Fragment) would be safer?

I like your remark, but since I do not have much information about the context it led me to thinking that firstFiveLetters was alredy in JSX. I am a newbie, and in these situations I get to learn!

Your method returns string, not react elements, thats why <br>  renders as string not as line-break tag. This is how i would do that with React:
const firstFiveLetters = chartData.centerText.slice(0, 5);
const remainingLetters = chartData.centerText.slice(5);

return (<>{firstFiveLetters}<br />{remainingLetters}</>);

as you can see in this case we will return React node, not string. You can even create component for this kind of formatting.
function LineBreakTextFormat({ text, first = 5 }) {
  const start = text.slice(0, first);
  const remaining = text.slice(first);
  return (
    <>
     {start}
     {!!remaining && <><br />{remaining}</>}
    </>
  );
}

// And then use it like this
<LineBreakTextFormat text={chartData.centerText} first={5} />




<div id="yourElementId"></div>

<script>
    // Assuming chartData.centerText is defined and is a string
    const chartData = { centerText: "HelloWorld" }; // Example data
    const firstFiveLetters = chartData.centerText.slice(0, 5);
    const remainingLetters = chartData.centerText.slice(5);

    // Create the HTML with the line break
    const formattedText = `${firstFiveLetters}<br>${remainingLetters}`;

    // Inject the formatted text into the HTML element
    document.getElementById('yourElementId').innerHTML = formattedText;
</script>




Please explain how this would actually solve the issue then?
